In BigQuery sandbox, when I type table id manually the id doesn't get underlined and couldn't run the query why
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.country_summary`

When the table ID automatically gets displayed the query editor the table ID seems underlined and the query runs successfully. But when I try to do the same by manually typing the table ID it doesn't get underlined and I couldn't run the query.
I am trying to manually type the table ID in big query to query a table but I am getting error message.

Syntax error: Unexpected string literal 'bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.c...' at [1:14]

This is the error message I get when I try to do so.

I copied and pasted your query into my BigQuery Studio environment and it worked.  I then tried to type if by hand, and it still worked.  Let's try and capture EXACTLY what you are doing.  I am using BigQuery Studio, have opened a query editor and am typing in the query you describe.

when you type it, you need to enclose it in backticks

I am new to bigquery . I have been using single quotation instead of backticks while entering table Ids and that resulted in errors. Thanks for letting me know @jeffreyohene.
